# How to 'merge' two beans, but sum numeric values inside

Tags: java

If I have a bean such as

```
public class SimpleBean
{
    private String name;
    private int int1;
    private int int2;
    private double double1;
    private double double2;

    // getters/setters snipped
}
```

what is the best way to merge two instances of the bean into one, where we only want to add the numeric values from the second bean instance to the first (i.e. we don't care about the String 'name' above)

I have come up with the following solution using PropertyUtils, but am thinking it is probably not the best

```
public void mergeStats(Object stat)
{
    try
    {
        Map<String, Object> beanMap = PropertyUtils.describe(stat);

        // Remove ones we don't want to merge
        beanMap.remove("name");
        beanMap.remove("class");

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry:beanMap.entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Number value = (Number) entry.getValue();

            Number existingValue = (Number) PropertyUtils.getProperty(this, key);
            BeanUtils.setProperty(this, key, existingValue.doubleValue() + value.doubleValue());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit: I will also add that the real bean for our project contains about 100 ints & doubles, and those can change over time as business requirements change.  Maintaining a function that handles each one by name is not too appealing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're building a framework, I'd discourage using BeanUtils, or reflection in general, for this sort of tasks. It doesn't give you any flexibility (you still have to name yourself the fields you don't want to include, whenever something is added to `SimpleBean`).

Adding properties explicitly has the advantage of being predictable and — if they become numerous — to rethink the design: perhaps arrays should be used?

Otherwise, to improve your current solution, you could check for the type of the property with `PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(...).getPropertyType()`, and thus discover if it can safely be cast to `java.lang.Number`, or other primitive wrapper class.

Comment: Why is BeanUtils/PropertyUtils discouraged?  It is performance reasons? The reason I used it as a first pass is because of its flexibility. I can add/remove the int/double fields and not have to modify the merge function.

Comment: @CollinPeters If a property must be added manually anyway, there's no big work in adding it to the summing function. I discourage BeanUtils, because they bring obscurity to the code. If I were you, I'd put it the other way round: I'd write all code **explicitly**, but I'd write a **unit test** using BeanUtils to check if all number properties are summed up.

Comment: is bang on.  Concrete class should have each field declared, unit test should use BeanUtils

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to the bean:

```
public SimpleBean mergeWith(SimpleBean other) {
    return new SimpleBean(this.name, 
                          int1 + other.int1,
                          int2 + other.int2,
                          double1 + other.double1,
                          double2 + other.double2);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify that I have close to a 100 ints & doubles in my class.  I would choose this approach however if I had a small known set.

Comment: Well, if you were able to declare and use these 100 numbers in the class, you should be able to copy them to another instance.